# Is it possible to make birthdays appear as "free" instead of "busy" in the calendar?

Tags: 8.1, calendars, lumia-925, google

I have a Google account containing my contacts. This automatically generates a `Birthdays` calendar (in the same Google account), with all the birthdays of my contacts.

If I choose to display this calendar in Windows Phone's native `Calendar` app, the events corresponding to my contacts' birthdays appear with a **busy** status.

Is there a way to make them appear with a **free** status? (I didn't find any setting for that neither in Google Calendar nor in the Windows Phone Calendar app.)

It would be great if I could make these events have a free status because currently, whenever I have an appointment during the same day as the birthday of one of my contacts (which happens a lot because I have many contacts), it is shown as "in conflict" (with the two arrows pointing at each other), which is confusing (and a false alarm).